# Adding place holder by jquery doesn't work fine

Tags: validation, placeholder, input-field

I have a input field with id 'datepicker'

While validating, if date mentioned is not valid

I am empty the field and adding the placeholder

```
 if(validationfails)
 {
    $("#datepicker").val(''); 
    $("#datepicker").attr('placeholder',"MM/DD/YYYY")
 }
```

Now the input field doesn't have anything, but the placeholder is missing.

if I focus the input field and press "backspace"

The place holder "MM/DD/YYYY" appears

Comment: Use the HTML 5 property. Then you will not have to write a single jQuery code.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your code to this one. Enclose your IDs in quotes.

```
            if(validationfails)
        {
            $('#datepicker').val('');
            $('#datepicker').attr('placeholder',"MM/DD/YYYY")
        }
```

Comment: Thannks for replying., But sorry rashid, that was typo

Comment: It's working right? I checked it on my local machine.

Comment: Multiple things can cause this. (1) You are not including jQuery properly (2) Try to include all your code in jQuery ready function as in my code (3) if validationfails variable returns false then the code will not be executed so try to add `!validationfails`.  My code looks like this.             `(function($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
                validationfails = true;
                if(validationfails) {
                    $('#datepicker').val('');
                    $('#datepicker').attr('placeholder',"MM/DD/YYYY")
                }
        });
    })(jQuery);`